# Django: MemoryError from runserver

Tags: django, wsgi

I'm working on a site that works fine on its existing wsgi server, and fine with runserver in local dev. But now we're preparing to transfer it to a new server and are having trouble getting it to work, even though both servers and setups are close to identical.

In the process of debugging, I tried to fire up runserver on the new server (just for testing purposes of course) and get errors like:

```
TypeError: must be (memory error), not str
```

or

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 225, in serve_forever
    r, w, e = select.select([self], [], [], poll_interval)
MemoryError
```

Clearly this is related to some kind of memory constraints in the new server environment, but I'm not sure where to go from here. I suspect that if I can clear this up, the wsgi process will start running properly.

Suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: does your wsgi script give the same error? when you run it manually. does manage.py with no parameters run? does manage.py with any other commands such as 'synchdb' run?

Comment: at the risk of suggesting the obvious - is the memory maxing out? (or if it's shared hosting, do they put some kind of hard cap on memory usage?)  When you try to run the wsgi process do you get the same errors in your logs?  Also may help to give more details about your environment

Comment: Thanks for the responses. Sorry, I should have said this was on a cPanel/WHM system. I have answered my own question, below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is on a cPanel/WHM server (and we control WHM, i.e. we have root). The answer turned out to be the WHM option "Shell fork bomb protection," which prevents users from running what WHM perceives to be long-running scripts, or scripts that might consume too many resources. Disabling that option restored our ability to use runserver.